# How to create a .cur file on Mac OS X

Tags: mac, conversion, css, cursor

Does anyone know how to convert a GIF file to a CUR file for use as a CSS cursor on a Mac?  I've seen several applications for Windows that do this, but nothing yet for Mac.  Is there anything out there?

Answer (score 4):

I recently had to look a solution as well for a client request. I came across a freeware /donation-suggested plug-in for Photoshop available:

http://www.telegraphics.com.au/svn/icoformat/trunk/dist/README.html
http://www.telegraphics.com.au/sw/product/ICOFormat#icoformat

I know the answer comes years later but I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Looked everywhere, found nothing :-(.  Nearest possibility I found was the source code for a Gimp plug-in (for Windows, but at least there is some source): http://www.gimptalk.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=27573

[Gimp is available for OS X](http://www.gimp.org/macintosh/) at least, so you may be able to convert the plugin if it uses no internal windows APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Download [winebottler](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/) and [AniFX](http://portableapps.com/apps/graphics_pictures/anifx_portable), install AniFX into a standalone bottle. That's what I did. You'll need X11 as well.

Answer (score -1):

Graphic Converter for Mac will save to a .cur file format.

http://www.lemkesoft.de/en/products/graphicconverter/download/